# Date format - excel userform to access database (both 2003)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform in Excell 2003 - a text field is autopopulated with todays date:

```
InDate.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

This worked the end of last month sending it to Access datebase in the dd/mm/yyyy formatt.

Today the date shows in excel userform as 02/03/2015 - when it is submitted to the Access table it is set as 03/02/2015. I have set the field in the table as 'Date/Time' with the Format as 'Short Date'. Default value is Date().

When I look at the table it shows the date on the next blank row autofilled with the correct formatt but when I submit from the excel userform it changes to mm/dd/yyyy again.

Been searching and trying to sort this out all day!

Thanks.

Tom

Comment: What is your system localization setting for date format?

Comment: Hi all, I have made some checks. Some users - the date is appearing fine, other users itis incorrect - I have checked the date in the bottom right of the screen which is also showing correct(4 March 2015) - does this mean that their localization settings are correct? I have changed the code from formatting to dd/mm/yyy to just using DATE. My IT department have said that there should be no problems with the users settings. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It's a localisation issue, I reckon.

US locale formats dates like `mm/dd/yyyy` while for instance, UK locale formats dates like `dd/mm/yyyy`. You need to just your system locale.

I hope this link would be helpful to you: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer - unfortunately I am unable to change the system locale. The files (access database and Excel userform) are stored on a shared network drive so everyone can access it. Are there any clever ways around this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You would need a UDF (User Defined Function) to switch dd and mm whenever one is larger than the other!